# Why is this program showing error expected expression before 's'

Tags: c

this is a program to take input using stack.I don't understand why is it showing error representing scanf can anyone explain the error

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stack 
{ 
  int top,n;     
}; typedef struct stack s;

int main(void) {
    scanf("%d",&s.n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s` names the `struct stack` type. Not an instance of that type.

What you can do is:

```
s a_stack;
```

and then use `&a_stack.n`

Answer (score 2):

`s` is a typedef which is not a variable of `struct stack` to access members in the structure. To access member variables, first declare a variable of type `s` and then access members in them.

```
s variable;
scanf("%d",&variable.n);
```